# Changing my connection in my java code

Tags: java, nodes

I just want to know is there a way to alter this code, so the code will be connected to my SQL management studio instead of oracle.

From line 13 to 15, I believe it is connecting the parser to the oracle database. Since I use SQL server for database instead of oracle, how do I change that part, so this parser will be connecting to my SQL management studio, which is what I use. Do I need to put my SQL server name and password?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Parser {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{   Connection con = null;   
    PreparedStatement statement = null;  
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521:XE","2656866","SgxT1221");
    Scanner filename = new Scanner(System.in);
    String  inputFileName;
    System.out.print("\nName of the XML file to be read: \n");    
    inputFileName = filename.next().trim();
    File file = new File(inputFileName);
```

Comment: it is sql or mysql studio?

Comment: SQL, sql server managmentn studio. I'm curious, .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XE","2656866","SgxT1221); what's that equivalent to in my sql studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is using Oracle driver and trying to connect to Oracle. To connect to MSSQLServer you have to do the following things:

-

1. Replace Oracle Driver and URL with MSSQL values to

   ```
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE","2656866","SgxT1221");
   ```
2. Add MSSQLSERVER driver jar to classpath. You can download it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server

   Also do not import packages with *. * will  import all the classes from that package whereas you need only few classes from that package.

Comment: Stack Overflow users can help you if you are stuck, we won't write code for you. I suggested something you have to try that if that doesn't work, come back and comment or update your post with whatever you have tried. We will help you if you post like this `email me` then people will flag your post as spam.

Comment: hey sir just wondering atabaseName=DATABASE","2656866","SgxT1221",, will my database be the same name? Also how do I found out my password?

Comment: You need to update HOST, username and password with the credentials you use for MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: thanks sir I think the port number is same, but how do I found out host? is that the database name I need to replace it with?

Comment: HostName is the machine name or IP address to which you connect to access your database.

Comment: thank you sir, also I downloaded the microsoft jdbc thing, once I run it, do I have to put into my eclipse file folder?

Comment: I hate to keep bother you,but is there way we can do google hangout? it will be less than two minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following to:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE","2656866","SgxT1221");
```

Comment: hey sir can I email you, I can't post another question, my email is gethbonow on gmail. Please consider helping me! I'm really lost rying ot fix this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@:1521:XE","2656866","SgxT1221");
```

replace above code with below lines of code.

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
 con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\XE;user=sa;password=secret);
```

Comment: Hey sir curious is 2656866 and sgxt1221, what should the equal to my in SQL server? and how do I found my my local host number? localhost:3306/XE"

Comment: 1433 is your port number .

Comment: 2656866 and sgxt1221 are the default username and password of your server.

Comment: sir 2656866","S‌​gxT1221, how do I found what those two thing in my sql studio?

Comment: you are using mysql or sql?

Comment: sorry i can help you only to solve your problem but not in writing in your code, so if you have any doubt you can ask here.

Comment: i have already given solution to you please make changes in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change your two line code as below:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE","2656866","SgxT1221");
```

Also add the [mySQL jar download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjar.htm).